# Using random() function on multiple threads

Tags: ios, multithreading, random, thread-safety

I'm working on an app where I need reproducible random numbers. I use `srandom()` with a seed to initialize the random number sequence. Then I use `random()` to generate the random numbers from this seed. If this is the only thread generating random numbers, everything works fine. However, if there are multiple threads generating random numbers, they interfere with each other.

Apparently, the sequence of random numbers is not thread safe. There must be a central random number generator that is called by all threads.

My app generates hundreds of objects, each one of which has four sequences of 14 random numbers generated this way. Each of these 4 sequences has its own non-random seed. This way, the random numbers should be reproducible. The problem is, because of the thread interference I just described, sometimes the sequence of 14 numbers being generated will be interrupted by a random number request by another thread.

After thinking about this for a while, I've decided to call

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//generate the 14 numbers});
```

to get each sequence. This should force them to get generated in the proper sequence. In reading the documentation, it says there could be a deadlock if `dispatch_sync` is called on the queue it's running in. How can I tell if I'm already on the main queue? If I am, I don't need to dispatch anything, right?

Is there a better way to do this?

I suspect another way to do this is similar to this but using a dedicated queue instead of the main queue. I've never tried making my own queue before. Also, the method that needs to call the queue is an ephemeral one, so I'd need to somehow pass the custom queue around if I'm going to go that route. How does one pass a queue as an argument?

For now, I'm running with my idea, above, dispatching synchronously to the main queue, and the app seems to work fine. Worst case scenario, this snippet of code would be run about 4800 times (4 for each of 1200 objects, which is currently the max.).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want computationally random numbers, rather than cryptographic random numbers.

My suggestion would be to have separate RNGs for each thread, with each thread RNG seeded centrally from a master RNG.  Since the system RNG is not thread safe, then create your own small RNG method -- a good LCG should work -- for use exclusively within one thread.

Use the built-in `random()` to produce only the initial seeds for each of your sub-threads.  Setting the overall initial seed with `srandom()` will ensure that the thread local `my_random()` methods will all get a consistent initial reseed as long as the threads are started in the same order each time.

Effectively you are building a hierarchy of RNGs to match your hierarchy of threads.

Comment: What are RNG and LCG? Sounds like government agencies.

Comment: Hmmm. Apparently, RNG = Random Number Genrator and LCG = Linear Congruential Generator.

Comment: Correct.  My apologies for the jargon.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have a singleton do the computation. The object needing the set of random numbers would ask the singleton for them in a batch.